# Simple MCU that can run Python commands

Tags: microcontroller

I’ve been trying to learn as much as I can about MCUs.  I’ve built a few custom PCBs for hobby projects here and there using SMD ESP modules and building all of the peripheral circuitry, but I feel like this is still very close to prototyping, and I still even use the Arduino IDE on my boards.

I’d like to have an MCU with more capabilities that could run some of the more demanding data analytics commands in Python, and really be something that can help me learn and get me out of the basic prototyping phase.

Does anyone have a recommendation for an MCU and or class of MCUs for someone like me?  I know asking for a part recommendation is outside of the forum guidelines so I would be happy to settle for some words of wisdom if you cannot share an exact module.

Comment: If you want a Python platform that’s more capable than micropython on an ESP32 then I suspect you’ll need to look at a small Linux platform such as a Pi Zero.

Comment: I would like to buy the board myself instead of purchasing a microcontroller board.  Does this mean I’d have to get a Linux OS to run the python engine? I imagine this would be very difficult to design the hardware

Comment: @Feynman137 You don't need Linux to run Python. You can set up a stand-alone system. It has been ported already to run directly on hardware, without an OS. Look up its use as "firmware," "ACPI," and "UEFI." That said, you really need to define how you want to use it, then. For example, would you imagine hooking it up via USB to a PC and then using PuTTY via virtual COM ports to access different Python sessions, which you'd "timeshare" out? (You can design it so that your Python supports multiple COM ports, simultaneously.) Or what, exactly?

Comment: Some MCU can run linux and certainly some lightweight python build, but if you intend to use that for data analytics, the performance will be really poor and it is probably not the right way to go. Ported versions of python are usually very limited and certainly won't have data analytics package.

Comment: go to [here](https://circuitpython.org/downloads), subset of python.

Comment: @Feynman137 Also, for processing power I've been using ODROID-C2 for a while. (More than a year.) I think the ODROID-XU4 is faster still, perhaps. But I don't own one.

Comment: I misspoke in my second comment “I would like to build my board instead of buying a microcontroller board” I already have plenty of these.  @jonk I would prefer to be able to SSL so MC would need to be WiFi compatible.  But I would be fine with a wired lcd display and editing code using the display.  Also  I don’t know much about circuit python but it seems like something very similar to Arduino IDE

Comment: @Feynman137 The ODROID-C2 comes complete with HDMI 2.0 4k port, 4 USB port host hub, 1000 Mbit ethernet, WiFi, and bluetooth, among other things. It makes a decent Roku box, for example. (Amlogic S905 SoC, 4 x ARM Cortex-A53 1.5GHz, 64bit ARMv8 Architecture @28nm.) Easily beats the Pi3. However, if you are going to do this stand-alone, you will have to pull together your own trusted and validated library set (or read doc and write code like a banshee.) Driving an LCD would be easy -- lots of I/O. Not pushing it. Just have it, is all. I'm sure there are lots of good choices.

Comment: _"I’d like to have an MCU with more capabilities that could run some of the more demanding data analytics commands in Python..."_ - Exactly how demanding? Would that include something like pandas/numpy/tensorflow? Note that those things come with a significant C runtime dependency, which may basically require a complete OS. I suspect that what you want might be a very poor fit for an MCU, but it's hard to judge without knowing what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments - 'more demanding data analytics commands in Python' suggests you need a lot of ram. If you have a lot of ram you probably want memory management and virtual memory along with that.

You've clearly moved into Linux territory (a' la RaspberryPi) if that is the requirement. This is the likes of the ARM 'A' (application) processors which are generally many 100's of MHz with a large external slab of dram.

Almost invariably the parts are BGA - both the microprocessor and the memory and require a lot of expertise in pcb layout and circuit design. These are higher power and frequency devices that need care and attention. It's not to say a hobbyist can't do it as many do, but there's a lot of learning involved.

Then there's the issues with getting boards manufactured etc. You can do this at home, but there's a bit of investment in equipment and time. In short, the complexity has risen exponentially.

The microcontroller class of processors (eg ARM 'M' series) are targeted to control application predominantly. This usually involves fast and precise timing of events.

You've got the likes of MicroPython/CircuitPython which you've probably come across with your ESP32 adventures, but these are devices with limited resources. With many microcontrollers you can bolt megabytes of ram onto them but past a point you really want memory management and virtual memory.

I can't understand why you're hung up on this 'prototype' thing. Just about every production board begins as a prototype.

A recent open source project I've been involved with we decided to use a Teensy 4.1 board and an ESP32 module. We had the skills to put the complete design onto one pcb, but the costs associated with going into production with a board with 50+ tiny components, BGA etc and having to source all the parts and so on would've made the project way more complex than required. In the end we just used a simple 4 layer pcb that the Teensy 4.1 plugs into that we get produced at a popular pcb offshore pcb company using their super cheap SMT assembly and we we able to use parts from their inventory. We've been able to crank out nearly 200 boards during this massive worldwide component shortage issue that's happening at the moment. We even designed the pcb using EasyEDA.The board looks as professional as you'd expect and we've been able to sell them at a favourable price (apart from a bit of contingency, there's zero profit). It also came first in a Hackaday competition.
We'd still be tied up trying to produce the first batch had we gone the 'long' way.

(tl;dr> Concentrate on the value you add. If that means using modules etc, then that's a perfectly sensible solution.